# Customize email regexp to allow insert hyphens

Tags: javascript, regex

I have email regexp which looks like this:

```
/^[_a-z0-9]+(\.[_a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,10})$/
```

The challange is to allow insert hyphen '-' before @ symbol, but with some restrictions:

1)E-mail can't start with hyphen

2)Hyphen can't be before @ symbol.

3)2 hyphens in a row '--' aren't allowed.

Comment: Try replacing the first `\.` with `[.-]`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Almost works. But I still can to insert 2 hyphens in a row and emails with few hyphens should work (like ww-ww-ww@gmail.com)

Comment: [It does not](https://regex101.com/r/pSoitt/2).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes. I didn't add .- in seperate group ([]). Works perfect. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may replace the first `\.` with a `[.-]` [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) that matches either `.` or `-`:

```
^[_a-z0-9]+(?:[.-][_a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9-]+)*\.[a-z]{2,10}$
              ^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pSoitt/3)

I also removed unnecessary groupings and converted capturing groups to non-capturing to streamline matching.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
^[_a-z0-9]+(\.[_a-z0-9]+)*@(?!.*--)[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,10})$
```

> 3)2 hyphens in a row '--' aren't allowed.

See https://regex101.com/r/r7iCEN/1